# Mostrar enlace al pasar ratón por encima CSS

Tags: html, css

Tengo una tabla donde tengo sus celdas agrupadas por clases. Estoy intentando que al pasar el ratón por encima del texto de la celda muestre ese texto más un enlace.Tiene que ser con CSS.

¿Como puedo sacar el enlace?

```
.clase1:hover::after{
 }
```

Comment: a[href]{
    visibility: hidden;
} .clase1:hover::after{
    visibility: visible;
    
} Lo tengo asi y no funciona

Answer (score 3):

Te dejo un pequeño ejemplo que puede servirte, oculta y muestra un `div` al pasar el ratón por encima.

Código:

```css
#show,#hide {
 display:none;
}

div#content {
 display:none;
  padding:10px;
  background-color:#f6f6f6;
  width:200px;
  cursor:pointer;
}

input#show:hover ~ div#content {
 display:block;
}

input#hide:hover ~ div#content {
 display:none;
}
```

```html
<label for="show">
   <span>[Mostrar]</span>
</label>
<input type="radio" id="show" name="group">

<label for="hide">
   <span>[Ocultar]</span>
</label>
<input type="radio" id="hide" name="group">

<div id="content">Contenido a mostrar</div>
```

Espero que pueda servirte!

Comment: Considero que una pequeña explicación del selector usado y como ayuda a responder la duda ayudaría mucho

Answer (score 3):

- Se me ocurre que como estas usando la *pseudoclase* `after` generes en la propiedad `content` el valor del enlace de tu etiqueta `a`
- considerando que solo lo buscas con CSS el dinamismo estará un poco limitado:
- Es opcional usar `before` o `after` para mostrar la posición que respecto de la etiqueta ocupará el valor enlace pasado

```html
    <!DOCTYPE html>
    <html>
    <head>
      <meta charset="utf-8">
      <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width">
      <title>JS Bin</title>
      <style>
        a:hover::after{
          content: " Enlace: https://demo.com"
        }
      </style>
    </head>
    <body>
    <a href="https://demo.com">demo sitio</a>
    </body>
    </html>
```

Comment: a[href]{ visibility: hidden; } .clase1:hover::after{ visibility: visible; } Lo tengo asi y no funciona. a href esta dentro de clase1

Comment: @Airsa97 esos detalles deben ir por favor en la pregunta para entonces tener un contexto mas amplio del problema

Answer (score 1):

Puedes hacerlo usando `>` en el selector:

```css
.link {
  display: none;
}

.celda:hover>.link {
  display: inline;
}
```

```html
<div class="celda">
  texto de la celda <a class="link" href="http://ejemplo.com">link1</a>
</div>
<div class="celda">
  texto de la celda <a class="link" href="http://ejemplo.com">link2</a>
</div>
```

> El combinador > selecciona los elementos que son hijos directos del
>   primer elemento. [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/CSS/Selectores_CSS)